# Как сделать поиск по нескольким полям таблицы

Tags: java, sql, jsp

на данный момент поиск работает отдельно по каждому полю (для каждого поля создан свой сервлет, и страница jsp для вывода данных) с помощью такого запроса

```
"select osdch_c||osdch_r As osdch, osdk_c||osdk_r As osdk, kiz, svi, kol, koliz from clippersql.vp44150sql where osdk_c||osdk_r like'%" + osdk + "%'" + " order by osdch_t " + " limit " + 100 + " offset " + (page - 1) * 100;
```

А вот как сделать что бы поиск был по всем полям (как в интернет магазинах например), не знаю, подскажите кто знает.

Comment: что значит по всем полям ? сейчас ваш запрос (почти) равноценен двум like через оператор OR, что дает выборку если значение хотя бы в одном поле. Если надо проверить на наличие обоих то использовать стоит AND (ну собственно как и в любых языках программирования)

Comment: смотрите по примеру интернет магазина, захожу в поиск выбираю в первом поле мобильные телефоны, оно выдает допустим 10 штук, потом я во втором поле пишу например самсунг, мне выдает 3 телефона, и например в третьем поле указываю цену, мне остается 1 девайс, вот такой же поиск нужно сделать мне (что бы можно было искать по разным полям, или по одному не важно какому, первому, второму и тд.)

Comment: Я бы, видимо, в своей программе динамически формировал запрос. Т.е. поле osdk!=null -- добавляю в нужное место запроса osdk_r like'%" + osdk

Comment: значит добавляете в запрос условия через AND в случае если человек что то ввел в это условие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделал так : `"select osdch_c||osdch_r As osdch, osdk_c||osdk_r As osdk, kiz, svi, kol, koliz from clippersql.vp44150sql where osdch_c||osdch_r like'%" + osdch + "%'" + " and osdk_c||osdk_r like '%" + osdk + "%'" + " and kiz like '%" + kiz + "%'" + " and CAST(svi AS text) like '%" + svi + "%'" + " order by osdch_t " + " limit " + 100 + " offset " + (page - 1) * 100;`

Может кому поможет.